# SharePoint Using Angular Material

Tags: 2013, design

I am using angular material for designing in SharePoint. All works fine until some attributes are used(hide-xs, layout-xs) and it leads to server error.

Is it best practice to design using angular material in SharePoint? If it so why when using hide-xs, layout-xs leads to server error?